# Headless browser detection

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, puppeteer, headless-browser

Do you know any webapps/online tests/online firewalls that are trying to detect if user is using selenium/puppeteer/phantomJS or any other headless browser?

I've created my puppeteer online crawler. I've changed many different stuff like `window.navigator` object (user-agent, ~.webdriver etc.).

Now I want to make sure that it is undetectable.

Answer (score 27):

There is a [headless browser detection test](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html) which tests for the following:

- Does the User-Agent contain the string "HeadlessChrome"?
- Is `navigator.webdriver` set?
- Is `window.chrome` unset?
- Does the browser skip asking for permissions (like notifications)?
- Are browser plugins unavailable?
- Is `navigator.languages` unset?

If your browser answers any of these questions with yes, then you fail the test. For more information on the test, check out this [post](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/), which is a reply to a post called ["Detecting Chrome headless, new techniques"](https://antoinevastel.com/bot%20detection/2018/01/17/detect-chrome-headless-v2.html).

The author of the latter post also published another test [test](https://antoinevastel.com/bots/) ([code](https://github.com/antoinevastel/fpscanner)), which claims to be able to detect bots and crawlers. It performs various tests on browser attributes and generates a fingerprint of your browser.

Other "soft" tests done by websites, might include the mouse movement, scrolling behavior, IP address, etc. I doubt you will find many tests regarding these information as this is basically a cat-and-mouse game.

Comment: Well I have all green: https://i.imgur.com/vnG9Pok.png but then I navigate to youtube they still know that I'm using webdriver somehow: https://i.imgur.com/xxkyo7l.png

Comment: They don't show any videos and don't show comment section so they somehow still able to detect webdriver. Do you have the knowledge how it's possible?

Comment: I also commented there to ask same question.

Comment: @BT101 There a many other techniques that a website might use to detect a headless browser. These are only the "simple" ones. Maybe the second test in my answer might help you. But it's very hard to say which exact technique they might use.