# my headless code does not work python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

hello my normally working code does not work in headless mode. Can you explain why?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
option = Options()
option.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
option.add_argument('--headless')


chromedriver = r'C:\Users\ozguc\Desktop\discord sesli\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,options=option)


URL = 'https://discord.com/channels/875038857517731871/875038857517731874'
driver.get(URL)

driver.execute_script("""
    function login(token) {
setInterval(() => {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
location.reload();
}, 2500);
}
login("token")
""")
time.sleep(10)
print("ok")
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="channels"]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/a')
print("done")
a.click()
```

I want to automate entering the sound room
normally my code works but when i pass it to headless=True it doesn't work

Comment: Any errors? What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"?

Comment: While it normally enters the audio channel, it currently does not.

Comment: who can help :(

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612934/some-websites-dont-fully-load-render-in-selenium-headless-mode

Comment: thank you so much :)))))))))