# 'Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable' occurs when the headless mode is enabled

Tags: jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I use Apache JMeter 5.4.1 and chromedriver 107.0.5304.62 for web page access test.
If I execute the test scenario without headless mode, and it succeeds.
But when the headless mode is enabled, the test failed and following error occurs.
[image]

**2022-11-16 09:21:45,271 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="sub"]/ul/li[5]/a (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'EC2AMAZ-HQV0HF4', ip: '192.100.1.13', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_351'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 107.0.5304.107, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a576..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DAISKA~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50048}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(direct), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: dbe1607372464587370fb424398e501b**

I changed the scenario(increased the wait time), but nothing changed.
The scenario is following.

**var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 120)
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="sub"]/ul/li[5]/a')))
var activity = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//*[@id="sub"]/ul/li[5]/a'))
activity.click()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Get the page source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()) and inspect whether the element is there
2. [Take the screenshot](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) and check whether the element you're looking for is there.
3. It might be the case you need to increase the resolution of the headless browser, something like:

   [image]
4. It might be the case the website you're testing behaves differently if it [detects that you're using a headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364643/headless-browser-detection)
5. There is a [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) so instead of waiting/finding/clicking you can use just one line which combines all actions:

   ```
   wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath('//[@id="sub"]/ul/li[5]/a'))).click()
   ```
6. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) mainly because [Groovy provides maximum performance comparing to other scripting engines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter). Moreover [JavaScript has been removed in Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you can face problems when you migrate to the most recent Java version.

Comment: I set "--window-size=1920,1080" to Additional arguments, and the test worked well.
Thank you for your advice.